# How to recover from changing OS X app name in Xcode?

Tags: xcode4.5

I'm a newbie using Xcode 4.5.2 on a MacBookPro. I'm working on an app based on AMSerialPort, and wanted to change the app name. In Build Settings>Packaging (project and target) I changed Product Name and in the summary I changed the Bundle Identifier. 
[image: Build settings]

On the next run it got the below error. The project builds OK. There were still some references to the old name (project and in finder the version col. showed it.
[image: Error message]

I read a lot of posts on this error and similar ones and none of the answers worked for me. I've tried pretty much every SDK and architecture, I've deleted the scheme and auto-created a new on, done a clean, closed the project, closed Xcode and restarted re-opened the project and no joy.

Trying to get all the names to match I changed the .xcodeproj name, opened it in XCode by double clicking it and now the Run and Stop button are disabled. Cmd B won't build it. All the files show in the list, and I can edit them.

Is there any hope of untangling my mess, or should I just unzip another copy? Doing that puts me back at changing the name.

Comment: You should post the build error too

Comment: There was no build error I saw, just a "bonk" sound.